# Pass array from checkboxes and insert multiple rows to database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox

Here is my view:

```
<?php foreach ($list_peserta as $show): ?>
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="undangan[]" value="<?php echo $show->email ?>" />
                <?php echo $show->nama ?></label>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Kirim" class="btn btn-info">
          </div>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller:

```
$data   =   array();
        $count  =   count($this->input->get_post['undangan']);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count ; $i++) {
            $data[] =   array(  
                                'id_acara'      =>  $this->input->post['id'][$i],
                                'email_peserta' =>  $this->input->post['undangan'][$i],
                                'status'        =>  ['Diundang'][$i]
                            );

            $this->db->insert_batch('kehadiran', $data);
```

I'm getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP5RA.png)

Please help!

Comment: Please avoid using links and/or images to offer content, code, and errors.  Your question will be improved if you copy-paste the text into your question.  Normally error messages are formatted as quoteblocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in this line. Don't use brackets or it looks like an array reference.

```
$count  =   count($this->input->get_post['undangan']);
```

I think it should be parenthesis...

```
$count  =   count($this->input->get_post('undangan'));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you get an error that essentially says `$this->input->get_post['undangan']` is not an array. Your first though should be to check to see what value that is giving you with a `var_dump`.

You would probably then notice that your syntax for get post is incorrect:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get_post

`$this->input->get_post(‘some_data’, TRUE);`

After following that scheme you shouldn't be having issues anymore. If you still are you need to verify that the variable is being sent. I don't know of a circumstance when I didn't know whether a variable is a `get` or a `post` so I would just make it one of those rather than using `get_post`.

Also generally it is a good idea to validate your inputs.

```
$var = $this->input->post('somevar');

if (is_null($var)) {
    show_error('missing params');
} else {
    // your logic
}
```